# Is a Polymorphic table slower than multiple tables

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, mariadb, polymorphic-associations

For my project, I have multiple tables with rows that can have assets (images, documents, ...). These assets can also be linked to different tables.
So, for every table that can have assets I currently have a pivot table (`asset_product`, `asset_publisher`, ...) that has two fields, an `asset_id` and a `row_id`. But this adds a lot of tables to the database.

I am completely reworking this project from scratch at the moment, and I was wondering if it wouldn't be better to add one polymorphic association here. In this case, I would only have one table that holds three fields: `asset_id`, `row_id`, `row_type`.

My question is: Is it a good idea to do this or will this affect performance when there are a lot of rows in this table? The current assets table holds about 60.000 assets, but this will grow immensely in the coming months.

Comment: Build a prototype, and test it.

Comment: To judge performance, we need to see the main queries.